# PartCover 2.5.3 win 7 x64

Tags: .net, 64-bit, partcover, corflags

Could you tell me how you got PartCover running with VS2008 and win 7 x64? Based on this post [How do I run PartCover in x64 windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256287/how-do-i-run-partcover-in-x64-windows), I ran

`c:\Program Files (x86)\Gubka Bob\PartCover .NET 2.3>CorFlags.exe PartCover.exe
/32BIT+ /Force`

with result

> Microsoft (R) .NET Framework CorFlags Conversion Tool. Version 3.5.21022.8 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. corflags : warning CF011 : The specified file is strong name signed. Using /Force will invalidate the signature of this image and will require the assembly to be resigned.

I also ran

`c:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0>CorFlags.exe nunit.exe /32BIT+ /Force`

with result

> Microsoft (R) .NET Framework CorFlags Conversion Tool. Version 3.5.21022.8 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Also, based on my discussion [Using PartCover 2.3 with .NET 4.0 runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546340/using-partcover-2-3-with-net-4-0-runtime/2964333#2964333), I also tried to use the x86 version of NUnit

What I'm trying to run coverage for is the c# money sample for NUnit 2.5.2

I get the same `System.Threading.ThreadInterruptedException` --->

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040153): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {FB20430E-CDC9-45D7-8453-272268002E08} failed due to the following error: 80040153

Thank you

**Edit:** same thing with PartCover 2.2

My settings:

- exe file: `C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console-x86.exe`
- working dir: `c:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.5.2\samples\csharp\money\`
- work arg: `/config=c:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.5.2\samples\csharp\money\cs-money.csproj
  rules: +[*]*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to this post, it's working now
http://www.planetgeek.ch/2009/10/15/get-partcover-running-on-x64-windows/
Please use PartCover 2.2. Both assemblies need to be changed with corflags

Comment: >corflags : warning CF011 : The specified file is strong name signed.

Answer (score 1):

I have started a fork of partcover on github which will handle .NET4 CLR (VS2010)

http://github.com/sawilde/partcover.net4

looking for people to test/raise issues/etc (or help develop)

Answer (score 1):

I am running Windows 7 x64 and have PartCover running properly. I got the source code from Shaun Wilde's fork (see the link in his answer to this question) and change the target CPU on all the projects from **Any CPU** to **x86** and then build.

After that I can get code coverage. I use nunit-console-x86.exe to run my unit tests in 32bit.

Comment: the latest release of PartCover should not need this fix